# time series in R with sales prediction with only date values

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, forecasting

i have a data with date(2015)with mm/dd/yy format  and sales.  I need to predict sales for 2016 with the given data. I just know, I need to use time series forecasting. However no idea. Since, many examples have only year like(1960,1970,..) my data has only one year with several months. Don't know how to plot too. can you give me a clear structure how to proceed?

Comment: This is too broad of a question. Start by reading up on time series. https://www.otexts.org/book/fpp that book has a lot of examples and uses R.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the date is in string and in the format mm/dd/yy

convert string into date by using this code

```
a <- "07/23/15"
b <- as.Date(a, format = "%m/%d/%y")
fullYear <- format(b,'%Y') // to get 2015 as year
halfYear <- format(b, '%y') //to get 15 as year
```

After this you can work on

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Converted sales figure into time series format.
plotted the data and seen whether there is any trend/Seasonality.

Since the data has only trend applied holts exponential smoothing under forecast package. Sales of 2016 has been found and plotted.